# Выдача сайта в поисковиках

Tags: php, html

Добрый день. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Написал сайт, работает он по принципу единой точки входа. Когда пользователь переходит на главную страницу то его запрос перенаправляется на index.php, который следующего содержания :

```
<?php

session_start();

  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/'){
    $currentPage = 'home';
  }else{
    $currentPage = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1);
    }


  if(file_exists('guest/'.$currentPage.'.php')) {
    include('guest/'.$currentPage.'.php');
  }elseif(isset($_SESSION['UsId']) && $_SESSION['UsAgent'] == md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])  && file_exists('auth/'.$currentPage.'.php') ){
    include('auth/'.$currentPage.'.php');
  }else{
    include('guest/nofound.php');
  }
?>
<?include("ad_content/footer.php");?>
```

Как вы видите, все что внутри тега **header** находится прямо в целевой странице в отличии от файла footer, который подключается напрямую в index.

Проблема в том, что когда я пишу в гугле название сайта, его www.domain.ru, то в результатах, вместо содержимого meta тега, выводится часть текста, который находится в файле footer. Я правильно понимаю, что когда робот индексировал страницу, то он брал её как есть, а не с содержимым $currentPage? Что делать? Переписывать подключение headera в index файле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно посмотреть, какую страницу получает поисковик при запросе с вашего сайта. Это можно посмотреть с помощью [сервисов Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?visit_id=1-636250719908445188-1914261348&rd=2). Если поисковик получает другую версию страницы, вы можете попробовать исправить это и проверить еще раз.

Если сейчас страница открывается нормально, возможно, в кеше Google висит старая версия и вы можете в тех-же инструментах вебмастера Google [попросить проиндексировать страницы заново](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=ru). Аналогичный сервис есть и у Яндекса.

Comment: Спасибо, проверил, все в порядке, попробую попросить повторную индексацию)